# Convert date to next day's date in iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios5, ios6, nsdate, xcode4.5

I have a date in string format just like `30-11-2012`. I want the date next to it like `01-12-2012` again in string format.
Is there any way of getting it?

Comment: Do you want to increase day by 1 as well as month by 1 in all the cases?

Comment: Not really, what I require is just the next date to my date.

just like if I have `31-12-2012` then I need the next date and that will be `01-01-2013 `

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got the answer by someone I forget the name, I was about to accept his/her answer but when I clicked on accept answer it told me that the post bas been removed.

The answer given by that anonymous person was given below

```
NSString *dateString = @"22-11-2012";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];
NSDate *dateFromString = [[NSDate alloc] init];
dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];


NSDateComponents *components= [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[components setDay:1];
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDate *dateIncremented= [calendar dateByAddingComponents:components toDate:dateFromString options:0];

NSDateFormatter *myDateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[myDateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];
NSString *stringFromDate = [myDateFormatter stringFromDate:dateIncremented];
NSLog(@"%@", stringFromDate);
```

In the end I really like to thanks that anonymous person, I know this was not as much tricky but this helped me a lot. Thanks again you the Anonymous Helper.

Answer (score 7):

You should use NSCalendar for best compatibility

```
NSDate *today = [NSDate dateWithNaturalLanguageString:@"2011-11-30"];
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents *dayComponent = [NSDateComponents new];
dayComponent.day = 1;

today = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:dayComponent toDate:today options:0];
//2011-12-01 12:00:00 +0000
```

Answer (score -1):

**swift 3.0**

```
var components = DateComponents()
components.day = 1
let now = Date()
let futureDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: components, to: now, wrappingComponents: false)
```

//now = 2017-03-22 futureDate = 2017-03-23

Comment: please add some description to explain answer.